# Custom Tabs asks for confirmation to open DeepLink in my app

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an OAuth2 process in my Android app implemented using Custom Tabs. I've configured `intent-filter` with custom `scheme`:

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="myhost"
            android:path="/mypath"
            android:scheme="mysheme" />
      </intent-filter>
```

It works correctly. OAuth2 process is being opened in Custom Tabs. When it completes, it redirects to URI with `myscheme` intercepted by my application.

However, very rarely, Custom Tabs (Chrome) displays dialog asking user to confirm that the link should be opened by my application. This is not standard "Open with..." dialog.

Is there a way to suppress this dialog in Custom Tabs?